# Why does IE fire the $window.onblur and $window.onfocus upon the page loads?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have here a simple snippet in AngularJS.

```
$window.onblur = function() {
    console.log('BLURRED');
}
$window.onfocus = function() {
    console.log('FOCUSED');
}
```

I noticed that the behavior is different in IE. Upon the page loads, it logs `BLURRED` and `FOCUSED` around 3 times even if I don't switch tabs/programs. This works normally in Chrome. Also I noticed that clicking on the page fires both `onfocus` and `onblur`. Is there a fix/alternative to this so it works normally in IE like in chrome?

Comment: Don't use blur or focus on the window object, it's rather overkill. If you need something to happen upon the page load use the init to run it. If you need to do something when you click on the page then use a click handler

Comment: @scrappedcola I need something that detects if the user leaves the tab and the user enters the tab. Is there anyway to do that without using my current implementation?

Comment: Try using addEventListener. Also where are you running this within the app?

Comment: @charlietfl I tried `$window.addEventListener('focus', function (){...});` but the behavior is still the same from above.